# How do I produce plain binary from object files?

Tags: c, gcc, binaryfiles, ld

How should I produce raw binary file from two object (.o) files?

I want the plain binary format produced by `nasm -f bin` when compiling a .asm file, but for .o files.

By a plain binary, I mean a file which contains only the instructions, not some extra information, as many executable files contain a lot of extra helpful information.

See http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html for information on that.

PS: I want to make a "plain binary" to start in [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page).

Comment: are you describing the linking process or something else?

Comment: All files are raw binary files. What do you actually want to do with the .o?

Comment: What I want is that I have two object files one from gcc and one from nasm, I can link them to produce a executable but how to produce a raw binary ?

Comment: By raw binary I mean a plain binary without the details which are included in the executable files.

Comment: (I wonder who is upvoting this) "a plain binary without the details which are included in the executable files" still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @wRAR Check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936844/what-is-the-difference-between-plain-binary-format-bin-and-windows-executable

Comment: @ps06756 and that question has answers that say mostly "there is no such thing".

Comment: I want the plain binary format  produced by `nasm -f bin` when compiling a .asm file.

Comment: `I want the plain binary format produced by nasm -f bin when compiling a .asm file` Include that in your question

Comment: And please explain why `nasm -f bin` is not [the correct procedure](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html).

Comment: @Jongware `nasm -f bin` produces plain binary from `.asm` source file, I want to produce the same thing from two `.o` object files.

Comment: It is a matter of invoking and scripting correctly the GNU `ld` binutils linker. BTW, plain binary executables cannot exist: you need at the very least a convention about the starting address and state (e.g. initial register contents). So please **edit your question** to explain why do you ask, and how would the produced "plain binary" be run (and be started)

Comment: I guess he wants a machine readable code, to run bare metal (without operating system)

Comment: @Vitor That's what I want!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This brings back memories. I'm sure there is a better way to do this with linker scripts, but this is how I did it when I was young and stupid:

```
# compile some files
gcc -c -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin kernel.c -o kernel.o
gcc -c -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -fno-builtin io.c -o io.o

# link files and place code at known address so we can jump there from asm
ld -Ttext 0x100000 kernel.o io.o -o kernel.out

# get a flat binary
objcopy -S -O binary kernel.out kernel.bin
```

The file `kernel.c` started with

```
__asm__("call _kmain");
__asm__("ret");

void kmain(void) { ... }
```

The fun part is writing the loader in assembler.

Answer (score 1):

`ld --oformat binary` is a more direct option:

```
ld --oformat binary -o main.img -Ttext 0x7C00 main.o
```

The downside of this method is that I don't think it is possible to reuse the symbols to debug, as we'd want something like:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda main.img -S -s &
gdb main.elf -ex 'target remote localhost:1234'
```

So in that case you should stick to `objcopy`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/895245

Also make sure that you use your own clean linker script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32594933/895245

Repository with working examples for some common cases:

- [boot sectors](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0/multiboot/hello-world/linker.ld)
- [multiboot interfacing with C](https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0/multiboot/hello-world/linker.ld)

Similar question: [How to generate plain binaries like nasm -f bin with the GNU GAS assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828631/plain-binaries-with-gnu-assembler)